# State and country picklist in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I configured the Billing Country and Billing State/province as picklist in salesfoce. The problem of this picklist; it contains just some of countr's state like Canada, US. When I choose US as country automatically the billing state/province displays list of state of US. But when I choode Belguim as Country I get None in billing state/province picklist. My question is How to import the Country's states/provinces list like Belguim.
Best regards

Comment: SO is not a code writing service; please review [ask].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

By default SF doesn't include any Belgium states, but you can add them yourself. Just go to Setup > Data Management > State and Country/Territory Picklists > Configure States and Countries and Territories. Find Belgium in the list and click "Edit" next to it. You'll see that it has 0 States and there will be a "New State" button.