# how to import states of my country in states/province picklist in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-lightning

I configured the Billing Country and Billing State/province as picklist in salesfoce. The problem of this picklist; it contains just some of countr's state like Canada, US. When I choose US as country automatically the billing state/province displays list of state of US. But when I choode Belguim as Country I get None in billing state/province picklist. My question is How to import the Country's states/provinces list like Belguim.
Best regards

Comment: Please don't ask identical questions on two different accounts
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42496866/state-and-country-picklist-in-salesforce

Answer (score 0):

you need to Create a Dependent Picklist feature in salesforce  where you can group different picklist fields and add their dependencies

See how it is done
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US&type=0